# find command to search for logs

Tags: scripts, find, rm

I need to search logs only in `a, b ,c, d, e, f` directories and not in the subdirectories

The command I use:

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs rm
```

which deletes important logs inside these subfolders. I don't want that.

Is there a way to delete `.log` files present only in `a,b ,c, d, e, f` and not in the subdirectories?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really want *"only in a ,b ,c, d, e, f"* (i.e. certain named directories) or do you really want to limit the *depth* of the search? if the latter, GNU `find` provides a `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 1):

Manually deleting log files is a very bad idea, especially, if these files are still being held open by the kernel. Please use and configure `logrotate` accordingly. For further details see - [Ubuntu manpage for logrotate](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/logrotate.8.html)

Comment: It is a good idea to explain on how to arrive to the solution other than just giving references.